# how to run a script using pyproject.toml settings and poetry?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

1. I am using poetry to create .whl files.
2. I have an ftp sever runing on a remote host.
3. I wrote a python script (`log_revision.py`) which save in a database the git commit, few more parameters and in the end send the the .whl(that poetry created) to the remote server ( each .whl in a different path in the server, the path is save in the db) .

At the moment I run the script manually after each time I run the `poetry build` commend.
I know the `pyproject.toml` has the   `[tool.poetry.scripts]` but i dont get how can i use it to run a python script.

I tried

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-script = "my_package_name:log_revision.py
```

and then `poetry run my-script` but I allways get an error 
`AttributeError: module 'my_package_namen' has no attribute 'log_revision'`

**1. can some one please help me understand how to run to wish commend?**

as a short term option(with out git and params) i tried to use the `poetry publish -r http://192.168.1.xxx/home/whl -u hello -p world` but i get the following error

```
[RuntimeError]                                 
Repository http://192.168.1.xxx/home/whl is not defined
```

**2. what am i doing wring and how can i fix it?**

would appricate any help, thx!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

At the moment the `[tool.poetry.scripts]` sections is equivalent to setuptools [console_scripts](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

So the argument must be a valid module and method name. Let's imagine within your package `my_package`, you have `log_revision.py`, which has a method `start()`. Then you have to write:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-script = "my_package.log_revision:start"
```

Here's a complete example:

You should have this folder structure:

```
my_package
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── log_revision.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

The complete content of a functional `pyproject.toml` is:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my_package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-script = "my_package.log_revision:start"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry_core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

and in `my_package/log_revision.py`:

```
def start():
    print("Hello")
```

After you have run `poetry install` once you should be able to do this:

```
$ poetry run my-script  
Hello
```

You cannot pass something to the `start()` method directly. Instead you can use command line arguments and parse them, e.g. with python's [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: thx for the link, tried it out it is only work for me when setting ```my-script = log_revision:start``` ( could not enter the package name).  in addition the ```log_revision.py``` should be in the **same level folder** as the ```pyproject.toml```

Comment: is there a way to send some data to the function ```log_revision:start(arg1, arg2)```?

Comment: [helpper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11306005/helpper) I had a hard time finding an example of how to pass arguments to the function, so I asked this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67476157/3954379)

Comment: How do you set this up so you can run the command directly like you can with `flask run my_app` with setuptools has `entry_points={"console_scripts": ["superset=superset.cli:superset"]}`

Comment: Poetry 1.1.13 raises `The Poetry configuration is invalid:
    - Additional properties are not allowed ('scritps' was unexpected)`

Comment: @Prometheus `scritps` looks like you've made a typo.

Comment: How do you get the VSCode Python debugger working with this setup?

Answer (score 36):

Although the previous answers are correct, they are a bit complicated. The simplest way to run a python script with poetry is as follows:

```sh
poetry run python myscript.py
```

If you are using a dev framework like `streamlit` you can use

```sh
poetry run streamlit run myapp.py
```

Basically anything you put after `poetry run` will execute from the `poetry virtual environment`.

Comment: Running a python script puts its folder at the beginning of the sys.path. If your script (or an imported module) imports http and there happens to be a an `http.py` in your folder, you will *NOT* get the python http module...

Comment: This pattern is useful for shell scripts / Makefiles. For example if you want to add a `make run` target to your repo because your fingers are tired, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 24):

For future visitors, I think what OP is asking for (a post build hook?) isn't directly supported. But you might find satisfaction from using a tool I wrote called [poethepoet](https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet) which integrates with poetry to run arbitrary tasks defined in the pyproject.toml in terms of shell commands or by referencing python functions.

For example you could define something like the following in your pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poe.tasks.log_revision]
script = "my_package.log_revision:main" # where main is the name of the python function in the log_revision module
help   = "Register this revision in the catalog db"

[tool.poe.tasks.build]
cmd  = "poetry build"
help = "Build the project"

[tool.poe.tasks.shipit]
sequence = ["build", "log_revision"]
help     = "Build and deploy"
```

And then execute and of the tasks with the poe CLI like the following which will run the other two tasks in sequence, thus building your project and running the deployment script in one go!

```sh
poe shipit
```

By default tasks are executed inside the poetry managed virtualenv (like using `poetry run`) so the python script can use dev dependencies.

If you need to define CLI arguments or load values into a task from a dotenv file (such as credentials) then this is also supported.

---

### Update: poetry plugin support

poethepoet can now support post build hooks when used as a poetry plugin. For example when using poetry >=1.2.0b1 you can configure the following to run your log_revision task automatically after `poetry build` is run:

```
[tool.poe.poetry_hooks]
post_build = "log-revision"

[tool.poe.tasks.log-revision]
script = "scripts:log_revision"
```

Comment: Excellent! Your tool is great. I experience though a small initialization lag when running a task (I guess due to some internal process sub-spawning).

Answer (score 6):

Tinkering with such a problem for a couple of hours and found a solution

I had a task to start the django server via poetry script.

Here are the directories. manage.py is in test folder:

```
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.rst
├── runserver.py
├── test
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── test
│       ├── asgi.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_tmp.py
└── tmp
    └── __init__.py
```

I had to create a file runserver.py:

```
 import subprocess                                                               
                                                                                   
  def djtest():                                                                   
      cmd =['python', 'test/manage.py', 'runserver']                                                                 
      subprocess.run(cmd)
```

then write the script itself pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]                                                           
dj = "runserver:djtest"
```

and still make changes to pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]                                                           
dj = "runserver:djtest"
```

only then command poetry run dj started working

Comment: Do you know if calling python via subproc invoked your poetry venv or uses the system?

Comment: To answer my own comment, yes it picks up the poetry venv

Comment: only then "dj" starts working

Comment: what are the differences between the last to code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about poetry, but you can use the more general:

```
[project.scripts]
script_name = "your_package.a_file:a_method"
```

That way also users that do not have poetry can a easy to access CLI script.