# Python project with Poetry: how to debug it in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, python-poetry

I have a Python project which I created according to basic Poetry [instructions](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/).

The project folder is something like this:

```
my-project
+----my_project
|    +-- my_project.py
|    +-- File1.py
|    +-- File2.py
|
+----pyproject.toml
```

Example of how I import stuff from one file to another: in `my_project.py` I have the code

```
from . import File1, File2
```

If I want to debug this from VS Code, if I try `F5` in the `my_project.py`, I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

However, if I don't express the imports like above, I can't run it using the `poetry` command.

In the `pyproject.toml` file, I have this:

```toml
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-project = "my_project.my_project:run"
```

`run` is the entry-point method in the `my_project.py` file.

To run the project from command prompt, I go to the project folder (where the package folder is) and I type `poetry run my-project`

Again, up to this point, everything according to [the Poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/).

How could I debug this project in VS Code?

I know I need to create a `launch.json` file, but I don't know how the configuration should look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For **Visual Studio Code**, you could try this:

- add an `__init__.py` file in the sub-directory `my_project`
- in the `.vscode` directory, add a `lauch.json` file with the following content:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "my-project",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "module": "my_project",
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, `cwd` points to your workspace folder, which should be the parent directory of `my-project`.
You should then be able to run successfully the `Run and Debug` module of Visual Studio Code.

As for **Poetry**, try modifying your `pyproject.toml` like this (there seems to be a typo, hyphen vs underscore):

```sh
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-project = "my-project.my_project:run"
```

And make sure to set the parent directory of `my-project` as your current working directory when you run `poetry run my-project`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316578/11246056) for additional guidance.

Comment: Should `__init__.py` file be empty ?

Comment: Hi, I don't think that the content of the `__init__.py` file matters in that case.

Comment: An empty `__init__.py` file tells python that the folder it is in is a package. This gets your import references working. You could also put python code into `__init__.py`, if needed. That code gets executed if someone imports from the package (i.e. named after the parent folder of the `__init__.py`. These files are one way of managing what exactly gets imported when you import a package. Not typically needed.

Comment: This approach results for me in `No module named my_project.__main__; 'my_project' is a package and cannot be directly executed.

Comment: is there any way to run poetry in the debugger script?

like `poetry run my-project`?

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers didn't work for me.

Here is the configuration of the `launch.json` file I needed to use to get the python debugger running on **Visual Studio Code** in a Poetry project.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "project debug", // Anything you want
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "C:\\...\\project", // full path to project folder
        "python": "C:\\...\\python.exe", // full path to python.exe (run  poetry env info --path) in terminal to get virtual env folder
        "program": "C:\\...\\file.py", // full path to file to execute
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "redirectOutput": true,
        "justMyCode": false,
        "stopOnEntry": false,
      }
    ]
  }
```

And here's the structure I use(d) for **Poetry** projects

```
C:.
│   poetry.lock
│   pyproject.toml
│
├───.vscode
│       launch.json
│
├───decon
│   │   file1.py
│   │   file2.py
│   │   ...
│   │   __init__.py
```

Answer (score 3):

In the project directory, create the file `.vscode/launch.json` with the following structure:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: <https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387>
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Your Project Name",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "module": "poetry",
      "python": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python",
      "args": [
        "run",
        "python",
        "-m",
        "uvicorn",
        "your_app_project:app",
        "--host",
        "localhost",
        "--port",
        "8000",
        "--debug",
        "--reload"
      ],
      "justMyCode": true,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "env": {
        "SIMPLE_SETTINGS": "your_env_value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Adjust the `name`, the `args`, and the `env` to fit your project. If you are using `pip`, the value of the module field should be `pytest`.

It is also possible to add more configurations and change them during development.

Answer (score 3):

None of above worked for me. I have tried this

First run `poetry debug info` and get your executable path
and then

```
{
  "version": "0.1",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Poetry",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "python": "your executeable path taken from command above",
      "module": "yourmodulename",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution using the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to set up a configuration in `launch.json`.

Using the Command Variable extension, we can use a "variable transform" to convert the current file path into a relative path **with dots**.

This would give the following configuration in `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python (Poetry): Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true
    }
  ]
}
```

So, for a project that looks like:

```
WorspaceRoot
┬───────────
│
├─┬─ .vscode
│ └─── launch.json
├─┬─ MyProject
│ ├─── __init__.py
│ ├─── file1.py
│ ├─── file2.py
│ └─── ...
├─── poetry.lock
├─── pyproject.toml
└─── ...
```

by running the configuration on an open file in `WorkspaceRoot/MyProject/file1.py`, the command `command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension` converts the file path into `MyProject.file1`. If you have the current Python environment set to be your poetry project, running this should run as a module (essentially `-m`).

If, however, you have a slightly different project structure, where `file1.py` is located in `WorspaceRoot/src/MyProject/file1.py`, then this needs additional work since the passed module will be `src.MyProject.file1`.

To remove the `src` prefix, we can make use an [input variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) along with the extension's command [`extension.commandvariable.transform`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#transform), as follows:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python (Poetry): Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "${input:PythonModuleName}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "PythonModuleName",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.relativeFileDotsNoExtension}",
        "find": "src\\.(.*)",
        "replace": "$1",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The regex pattern `src\\.(.*)` captures everything after the `src.` prefix, which is then substituted as the input to our original configuration via the `${input:PythonModuleName}` variable replacement.