# Poetry: how install nltk dependencies

Tags: python, nltk, python-poetry

I use poetry as a dependency manager and I need to install `nltk` dependencies

```
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
```

It is possible to add it into `pyproject.toml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it's not possible to run custom commands defined in pyproject.toml, it's been [discussed](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2496) for a while now though.

You can however:

1. Create a python script all call it with [poetry run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316578/5692012)
2. Use a wrapper like [taskipy](https://pypi.org/project/taskipy/) or [poethepoet](https://pypi.org/project/poethepoet/) to call any script/command from your poetry virtualenv