# Running a python script with poetry

Tags: python, fastapi, python-poetry

I'm currently in the process of migrating an existing project to use Poetry instead of a requirements.txt file for managing dependencies. I've successfully linked the necessary dependencies, but I'm facing an issue when trying to declare and run scripts, such as starting the server or creating a database. My server file is located at src/main.py within the project structure.

In my pyproject.toml, I've defined a script as follows:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "python src/main.py"
```

Following the documentation, I've executed *poetry install* to ensure the dependencies are installed. However, when I try to start my server using poetry run start, I encounter the following error:

```
Warning: 'start' is an entry point defined in pyproject.toml, but it's not installed as a script. You may get improper `sys.argv[0]`.

The support to run uninstalled scripts will be removed in a future release.

Run `poetry install` to resolve and get rid of this message.

not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and this is my initial experience with Poetry. I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue and successfully run my project with Poetry."

Following the documentation, I've executed *poetry install* to ensure the dependencies are installed. However, when I try to start my server using poetry run start, I encounter the following error:

Comment: [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316578/5640517)

Comment: IMHO poetry creates a virtual environment during `poetry install`. Why not activating said environment with `poetry shell` and run your script with `python your-script.py`? Anything keeping you from the activation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run a script using pyproject.toml settings and poetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59286983/how-to-run-a-script-using-pyproject-toml-settings-and-poetry)

Comment: Just to circle back on this question. I found that what I needed was a task runner. I opted for [poe the poet](https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet) for this and this solved my question here.

Answer (score 3):

"OK, so Poetry scripts are not meant to be used like npm scripts
They are when you create a package that exposes executable entrypoints (for example pytest gives the pytest command, or ansible with ansible and ansible-playbook)
[15:44]
What you're looking for could be poethepoet (https://github.com/nat-n/poethepoet), but maybe there are others" by @nymous" This is what solved my query.