# How to configure pyproject.toml for a pip package to enable one Python script to execute another via command line?

Tags: python, pip, command, pytest, pyproject.toml

I would like to create a pip package where one python script can execute the other script over the command line.

Take this as an example:

```
my-package/
└── my-package
    ├── script.py
    └── tests.py
```

with `script.py`:

```py
import pytest

def run():

    # run the other script
    pytest.main(["tests.py"])
    
    # then do the actual stuff
    print("I did something!")
```

and `tests.py`:

```py
import pytest

class Test:
    
    def test_stuff(self):
        if not 1 == 2:
            pytest.fail('1 does not equal 2')
```

How can I configure my `pyproject.toml` file so that the `run()` function inside `script.py` always "knows" where to find `tests.py` so it can execute it via [`pytest.main()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code)? Right now, I have the problem that the `run()` function expects `tests.py` to be always in the directory that I am currently in. Of course that's not the case. I need a way to tell the `run` function that it will find `tests.py` in the same directory where itself is located.

**Note:** I saw a few suggestions but they always refer to specific functions inside scripts that are made available as command-line options. But in my case one script should call the whole other script not just one single function inside of it.

Possibly related:

[how to run a script using pyproject.toml settings and poetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59286983/how-to-run-a-script-using-pyproject-toml-settings-and-poetry)

Comment: `importlib.resources` knows where to find things that are installed: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html

Comment: Sounds interesting, could you provide a code example?

Comment: Examples here: https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html -- Pay attention whether you choose to use `importlib.resources` from Python's standard library or `importlib-resources`. Documentation should be pretty much the same except you need to import and use either `importlib.resources` or `importlib_resources`.